# [SOLVED] rtabmap fails to run a bag of depth and rgdb images

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am playing a bag of 16 bits-per-pixel depth and 8 bit rgb images. While playing the bag, I can extract both the rgb and the depth images into files (to verify that the data is ok)
(I used the thread [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/313164/create-a-bag-out-of-16-bit-images/) to create and extract the depth images)

The way the depth image is stored in the bag is by using a python script that uses the PIL package to read a pgm image from file into a PIL object, serialize the object data into byte array (using io.BytesIO()), and save the byte array in PPM format.

To verify the data, I wanted to view the images first, before running rtabmap
In rviz I can view the rgb image, but I cannot view the depth image. According to [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/313323/rviz-not-showing-16-bits-per-pixel-single-channel-depth-images/):

> "RVIZ cannot view 16 bit images
> natively. You'll have to convert them
> to an 8 bit format."

So I assume that the images are correct and move on to use rtabmap
I launch rtabmap using the launch file below:

```
roslaunch ~/avner/PGR/vision/trunk/ros/catkin_ws/src/bpc_slam_rtabmap/launch/rgbd_slam.rgbd_dataset4.launch
```

But I cannot see the 3D map in rviz, and I do see error messages from rgbd_odometry

```
...
BEG getCvType
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv_bridge::Exception'
  what():  Image is wrongly formed: height * step != size  or  385 * 1280 != 492817
Aborted
```

The depth file is stored the bag in PPM format.
The data payload is 492800 (640*2*385)

- width: 640
- height: 385
- bytes per pixel 2
- step size 640*2 = 1280

The size of the file is 492817, due to the header payload

So actually, the details in the error message are correct ("height*step" should not be equal to "size")
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how to satisfy rgbd_odometry?

Thanks,

Avner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313325/%5Bsolved%5D-rtabmap-fails-to-run-a-bag-of-depth-and-rgdb-images/) by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-01-22**:
Looking at http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/cv__bridge_8cpp_source.html, the data in sensor_msgs::Image topic should not include the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by changing the way that the depth image is stored in the bag in the python script, to use cv_bridge instead of using the PIL.

After using cv_bridge to store the image without the header, rgbd_odometry does not abort anymore

See [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/313323/solved-rviz-not-showing-16-bits-per-pixel-single-channel-depth-images/) for more details

---

Originally posted by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) with karma: 96 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0